# axios return me request failed with status code 500 in post man and react native android app i'm using php api

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, axios

`Axios` return status `code 500`  this is php api using  in my react
    native app also tested in the postman

**Here is my code:**

```
    var bodyFormData = new FormData(); bodyFormData.append('name',
    'ali');
        bodyFormData.append('email', 'test@testw.con'); 
        bodyFormData.append('phone', '1111111111111111111'); 
        bodyFormData.append('password', '12345678'); 
        bodyFormData.append('password_confirmation', '12345678'); 
        bodyFormData.append('img', 'sssss'); 
        bodyFormData.append('carrer', '22245refdfd'); 
        bodyFormData.append('adress', 'eee33333333'); 
        bodyFormData.append('type', '11111111');  try{   const res =  await axios.post (url,bodyFormData,confienter code hereg)
        alert(JSON.stringify(res)); }catch(e){ alert(e) }
```

What is possibly wrong here? Can someone help me, thank you!

Comment: to understand the situation here, you're gonna need to attach the server side code too.

Comment: You should be getting a stack trace in PHP (server side) for the error. Sharing that along with the code would be required for resolving the issue.